# Using DataSource with Transaction using Spring

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data

I am working as part of a legacy j2ee application  (plain application no Spring or Hibernate support)
The application exposes the following method:

```
public DataSource getConnectionDataSource();
```

[DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) is properly initiated to a specific DB schema by the product.

When I want to query the DB I create a jdbcTemplate object and query the like so:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("PRINT_LOCA",printerLocation);
DataSource printersSchemaDS = context.getCommonServices().getConnectionDataSource("printersSchema");

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(printersSchemaDS);
String printerId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select printerId  from printers where printer_location=:PRINT_LOCA ",parameters,String.class);
```

My question is how can I execute multiple Update SQL statements in a single transaction when I only have the DataSource object?
I see that there is TransactionTemplate in Spring, but is it possible to initialize it with DataSource object alone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take single connection from datasource, then use ordinary manual jdbc transaction:

```
 try (Connection con = datasource.getConnection();) {

 con.setAutoCommit(false);
 // insert logic
 con.commit();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  // handle exception
  con.rollback();
 }
```

Full example here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html